# Hybrid app with Svelte and without webviews

Tags: hybrid-mobile-app

There are certain web technologies out there that enable hybrid apps without webviews.  Perhaps one of the most popular is React Native.  It enables you to render web UIs and native UIs with a single code base.  But there are many more technologies that seem to require webviews, but with an inherent performance penalty.  That performance penalty matters to me because the app I have in mind is a game that uses PIXI.js to render to a WebGL canvas.  I've already had to optimize a prototype PWA app to run smoothly on mobile devices.

I've done a lot of research on this subject and it is difficult to weed out the solutions that require webviews and solutions that only enable cross native app development using JavaScript (as opposed to a true hybrid that enable targeting web deployments as well).  Then solutions seem to become even more scarce when I want to include Svelte into my stack.

The solution that seems most promising to me right now is [svelte-native](https://svelte-native.technology/).  It uses NativeScript and I believe the expectation is that I would need to use native components when constructing my API.  What isn't clear to me is if I can also render the "native" components as web equivalents when deploying to the web.  Of course, I am also trying to make sure I can use PIXI.js in NativeScript as well.

What technology stack would you recommend that meet all of my requirements?  If you don't know of any, what requirement(s) would you recommend I give up?

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar. Did you reach a conclusion about this?